# How to select all checkbox using Itemcheck event?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

Can you guys help me code if I select one of the checkboxes on the ListView section, the rest of the checkboxes should be checked.

My ListView name is lvBase and I want to used the ListView ItemCheck events.

This is my code.

```
private void lvBase_ItemCheck_1(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Note that the [tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) guidelines recommend refraining from placing tags in your question title (see the section that starts _"Avoid inserting tags into titles in any of the following formats:"_)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use the following line to add an itemcheck or itemchecked event:**

```
 this.listView1.ItemCheck += new ItemCheckEventHandler(listView1_ItemCheck);
```

Comment: @Captain_Teemo i am in the service of every programmer

Answer (score 1):

Hope I understood your question correctly, If you want to check all the checkbox in the list, you can loop through them and set Checked Property to true.

```
    private void lvBase_ItemChecked(object sender, ItemCheckedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lvBase.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            lvBase.Items[i].Checked = e.Item.Checked;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to code "If you click the checkbox" at the front of your code?

Comment: @Captain_Teemo I have updated the code to check if it is checked. The updated code would mark remaining items as checked only if current item is checked

Comment: @Captain_Teemo hope that's what you meant by "if you click the checkbox"

Comment: It says that 'System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Item'

Comment: @Captain_Teemo Reconfirming facts -- lvBase is a listview and lvBase_ItemCheck_1 is the ItemChecked event of listview ?

Comment: If there is two buttons and when I click button 1, the button 2 is checked. And clicking the button 2, the button 2 check is erased and button 1 is checked. Your loop looks fine but cant get all the checkbox clicked..

Comment: @Captain_Teemo sorry, didnt understand. Are you talking about same functionality or new one that involves buttons ? I couldn't see button in the listview ? Also, 'clicked' or checked ?

Comment: Not button, checkbox. My mistake sorry! If there is two checkbox. If you click checkbox1 then checkbox1 should be checked, but checkbox1 isnt checked and checkbox2 is checked.

Comment: @Captain_Teemo got it. You should possibly do this from "ItemChecked" event rather than "ItemCheck" event. ItemCheck happens prior to value getting changed.,which is why the issue. I have updated the code with ItemChecked Event. Kindly check

Comment: If you see the picture that I posted at the top. There are no "ItemChecked" events.. So it says that "The type or namespace name could not be found". Can you help me with that? Sorry for asking so much

Comment: That is strange. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.itemchecked?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Well I will figure this out. Thank you helping me and sharing your knowledge :)